# Document will not load sources. Sublime Text

Tags: javascript, html

I just do not understand this. I'm on my PC right now, using sublime text and google chrome and my document will not load jQuery, it stays pending for awhile then fails. Now this works on my mac, using any kind of editor, but it seems whenever I use sublime on my PC this happens...

EDIT: Adding http:// to the script src will allow jQuery to load, but throws a 304.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("p").hide();
     });
 });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Blah</h2>
  <button>Blah</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I'll get jQuery failed 22.07s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do //ajax...  it dynamically attaches file:// protocol. Since we are doing it from local file system we need to be more specific with http://

I also have modified the code to correct certain mistakes like the missing of script tag. Added a p tag so that we can see the example working etc. Take a look.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("p").hide();
     });
 });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Blah</h2>
  <button>Blah</button>
  <p>  This will go away </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nvm, still throwing a 304 even with yous.

Comment: 304 is "not modified" and I wouldn't consider as an error. [link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Answer (score 0):

try :

append `http:` in src

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

OR remove `//` from `src`

```
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```